# How to reduce time complexity while mapping structs with sub-slices in go?

Tags: performance, go, struct, time-complexity

Let's say there's the following `Unload` struct, which comes as a single element response from microservice A, and where each `Item` initially has an empty `Units` slice:

```golang
type Unload struct {
    UnloadCode   string
    Orders      []Order
}

type Order struct {
    OrderCode    string
    Items        []Item
}

type Item struct {
    ItemCode    string
    Units     []string
}
```

And also a `ItemUnit` struct which comes as a slice response from microservice B:

```golang
type ItemUnit struct {
    ItemCode    string
    Units       []Unit
}

type Unit struct {
    UnitName    string
}
```

And we need to populate the `Item`, `Units` slice with it's corresponding `UnitName` values, based on similar `ItemCodes` on both sides.

I've managed to come up with the following solution, for solving this issue:

```golang
for orderIndex, order := range unload.Orders {
    for itemIndex, item := range order.Items {
        for _, itemUnit := range itemUnits {
            if item.ItemCode == itemUnit.ItemCode {
                for _, unit := range itemUnit.Units {
                    unload.Orders[orderIndex].Items[itemIndex].Units = append(unload.Orders[orderIndex].Items[itemIndex].Units, unit.UnitName)
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

I'm not a go expert myself, but it seems to me that this solution comes with a very high time complexity cost. Would there be any other, more elegant and possibly with a smaller time complexity, way of solving this issue?

*Keep in mind that I can't change the structure of any of my structs.

Comment: If the units are unique you could remove them gradually from the source slice so that each successive iteration has to go over less units then the previous one. Another option would be to first loop over the source slice and construct a map and then use the map for lookup by itemcode, however if the size of the source slice is small then using a loop for the lookup might be faster than the hashtable lookup. Also, if it is possible, you should change the slice element types from non-pointers to pointers, then you can avoid the verbose indexing.

Comment: @mkopriva I've tried to implement your pointers suggestion with no luck, could you provide a code sample of that?

Comment: https://play.golang.com/p/BEbV-GpbNen this will work because `item` points to the same value as `unload.Orders[orderIndex].Items[itemIndex]`

Comment: @mkopriva I get the following error while trying to use your implementation with actual data: `cannot use []Item literal (type []Item) as type []*Item in field value` https://play.golang.com/p/bgIpTB49LGC

Comment: https://play.golang.com/p/5ljQk8E9Ob7 If you declare a field as `[]*Item` you need to use `[]*Item` not `[]Item`. To initialize a slice of pointers-to-items you can use the literal `[]*Item{ ... }`. To initialize a pointer-to-item you can use the literal `&Item{ ... }`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

First, create a map for `ItemUnit` where `itemUnit.ItemCode` as key and slice of `UnitName` as value

```golang
    itemUnitmap := make(map[string][]string)
    for _, itemUnit := range itemUnits {
        var units []string
        for _, unit := range itemUnit.Units {
            units =  append(units, unit.UnitName)
        }
        itemUnitmap[itemUnit.ItemCode] = units
    }
```

Then use map to get slice of `UnitName` using `item.ItemCode`. Add slice into `Item.Units` using variadic function

```golang
   for orderIndex, order := range unload.Orders {
        for itemIndex, item := range order.Items {
            if units, ok := itemUnitmap[item.ItemCode]; ok {
                unload.Orders[orderIndex].Items[itemIndex].Units = append(unload.Orders[orderIndex].Items[itemIndex].Units, units...)// variadic function used to append slice into slice
            }
        }
    }
```

Comment: I've tried your implementation, it works fine but I run a benchmark against my implementation, and mine still faster. and as stated by @mkopriva "if the size of the source slice is small then using a loop for the lookup might be faster than the hashtable lookup", as was the case here: https://play.golang.com/p/5ljQk8E9Ob7

Comment: @rogerio-schmitt You want a smaller complexity solution thats why I use map, and yes, if source slice is small then using loop is fine, but for large dataset mine one will perform faster since its complexity is low.